# Quando devo usar a anotação @EnableAutoConfiguration e como ela funciona?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotation

A Anotação `EnableAutoConfiguration` deve ser usada em que tipo de projeto? e como ela funciona na aplicação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delfino, essa anotação faz parte do Projeto ***Spring-Boot***, projeto interessante pra quem deseja desenvolver Micro-serviços. Uma de suas principais caracteristicas do Spring-Boot é permitir que o Application Context do Spring seja automáticamente configurado baseando-se nos jars.

Propriedades da Anotação:

- A Auto-configuração é sempre feita **após** os *Beans* definidos por você terem sido registrados.
- A Auto-configuração tenta ser o mais inteligente possível para configurar interfaces da sua aplicação e diminui seu papel a medida que você define as configurações manualmente.
- Outra Característica importante da anotação, é sua propriedade ***exclude***, a qual você pode usar para definir as classes que você quer que não sofram configurações automáticas.

```java
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Aqui tem mais um link importante para você:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html